# Analogue signal issue?

Tags: pcb, amplifier, dc, converter, terminal

I have an issue with a analogue signal. Your help would be greatly appreciated.

The signal is a 5Vdc, it is an output from a PCB which is a source to many A/D PCB. its output is connected using wire of length around 3 meters to a breakout terminal. This point distributes the signal to other 4 places (A/D PCB) using long wire ( 10 meters) . the first stage of the A/D converter is a low-noise high-precision amplifier (TLE2027AID), the output of the A/D goes to a digital system which can be accessed using a software interface to read the digital value.

The issue I have is that when I inject 5 Volts at the source (before cabling), I read 5.1 VDC using the software, How is that possible to have more voltage than the input? capacitance effect is not there because it is DC.

Somebody can tell what could be the issue so I can do some more investigation? Any help would be great?

Comment: How do you know you are injecting 5volts? What about the ground reference. What about errors in your measurement of the 5V source?

Comment: And how you know that your AD-conversion would output 5.0V in case you had a perfect 5.0V input?

Comment: Yes okay . Thanks I am NOOB- as you can clearly see... only a score of 11 on this forum. I will double check with my meter and make sure that I am producing 5.0 V . Thanks for the Tip. Also maybe its a software problem ? Anyway thank you guys so much for helping out I really appreciate you taking the time to share your knowledge.

Comment: _"when I inject 5 Volts at the source (before cabling)..."_ - what happens if you inject the '5V' directly into the ADC instead of feeding it through the cable?

Comment: Draw it out; don't use words.

Comment: Ok great will do working on putting together the diagrams now.